EventCallback throws "The current thread is not associated with the Dispatcher"
I am trying to create a simple search input control with debounce functionality based on a Timer.
Search.razor:
<input type="search" placeholder="Search" @oninput=@((e) => SearchChanged(e)) />

@code {
    
  [Parameter]
  public EventCallback<string> OnSearchChanged { get; set; }

  private System.Timers.Timer? _debounceTimer;

  string Text = string.Empty;

  public void SearchChanged(ChangeEventArgs e)
  {
     Text = e.Value == null ? string.Empty : e.Value.ToString()!;
     // Debounce search
     _debounceTimer?.Stop();
     _debounceTimer?.Dispose();
     _debounceTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(200);
     _debounceTimer.Elapsed += DebounceTimerElapsed;
     _debounceTimer.Enabled = true;
     _debounceTimer.Start();
  }

  private void DebounceTimerElapsed(object? sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    _debounceTimer?.Dispose();
    OnSearchChanged.InvokeAsync(Text);    // <<< Dispatcher exception
  }
}

I think it makes sense to include the Debounce functionality with this component so I don't have to repeat it on each parent. But I can't seem to use an EventCallback to let the parent component know the Timer has elapsed. It throws the infamous The current thread is not associated with the Dispatcher exception.
This page on Blazor University explains that non-UI events such as Timer.Elapsed spawn on another thread. The Timer is indeed the culprit because obviously it works if I call OnSearchChanged.InvokeAsync() directly from SearchChanged. But InvokeAsync() does not seem to sync back to the UI thread in this case. Yet I think there should be a simple way to make this work.
Is there a (simple) way to let a parent component know that a Timer has elapsed in a child component?

FYI -  see these debounce implementations https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5308567/An-Easier-Blazor-Debounce and https://shauncurtis.github.io/Building-Blazor-Applications/Building-A-Blazor-AutoComplete-Control.html

Thx, @MrCakaShaunCurtis. As a matter of fact I had already found the first article on Jeremy Likness' blog.

The problem in decoupling the debouncer from the search logic, which is probably async and some sort of remote call, is you can still get a race condition where the search is slower than you debounce period.  If you tightly couple them, the you only do a new search after the previous has finished.

The error message you're encountering is common when trying to update the UI from a non-UI thread in Blazor. This situation often occurs in event handlers of asynchronous operations or timers, like in your case with the System.Timers.Timer. Since the timer's Elapsed event runs on a thread pool thread, not on the Blazor Dispatcher thread, attempting to modify component state directly leads to this error.
To fix this, you need to ensure that the UI update logic is executed on the Blazor Dispatcher thread. You can achieve this by using the InvokeAsync method to marshal the call back to the Blazor component's context. Here is how you can modify your Search method to use InvokeAsync:
(Assuming you'll re-use this component and want to @bind to it.
DebouncedSearch.razor

@using System.Timers
<input @bind="SearchText"
       @bind:event="oninput"
       autocomplete="off"
       type="text" />

@code {

    [Parameter] public string? Value { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<string> ValueChanged { get; set; }

    private Timer _debounceTimer = new();
    private string _searchText = string.Empty;

    private string SearchText
    {
        get => _searchText;
        set
        {
            _searchText = value;
            _debounceTimer.Stop();
            _debounceTimer.Start();
        }
    }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        _debounceTimer.Interval = 200;
        _debounceTimer.AutoReset = false;
        _debounceTimer.Elapsed += Search;
    }

    private async void Search(object? source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        await InvokeAsync(async () =>
        {
            await ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(_searchText);
        });
    }
}

Index.razor or any other parent
<DebouncedSearch @bind-Value="@searchText" />

<label>Text: @searchText</label>

@code {
    private string? searchText;
}


For anybody reading this:  the answer to the OP is in the way InvokeAsync is called; await InvokeAsync(async () = { await ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(_searchText); });
Binding the oninput event using the getter/setter as in this answer or using a void as in the original question is a matter of personal preference.

Your input code won't compile - for example input @bind-value="SearchText" should be input @bind="SearchText".  The same with @bind-value:event="oninput"

No Problem at all.

Here's a slightly different version to @Verbe's answer that :

uses bind:after to control the debouncer and pass updates up to the parent.
Uses the lightweight System.Threading.Timer.

@using System.Threading

<input @bind="_searchText"
       @bind:event="oninput"
       @bind:after="Debounce"
       autocomplete="off"
       type="text" />

@code {
    [Parameter] public string? Value { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<string?> ValueChanged { get; set; }

    private System.Threading.Timer? _timer;
    private string? _searchText;
    private int _debounceMilliseconds = 300;

    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        this._searchText = this.Value;
    }

    private void Debounce()
    {
        _timer?.Dispose();
        _timer = new Timer(this.OnTimerExpired, null, _debounceMilliseconds, -1);
    }

    private void OnTimerExpired(object? state)
    {
        _timer?.Dispose();
        _timer = null;
        // invoke OnValueChanged on the Synchronisation Context
        this.InvokeAsync(OnValueChanged);
    }

    private Task OnValueChanged()
        => this.ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(_searchText);
}

There is a problem in doing it this way. You decouple the debouncer from the search logic. If that logic is an async call to a remote service, you can still get a race condition where the search is slower than your debounce period.
